# Identify new records in a merged collection of objects in custom validation

Tags: ruby, merge, compare

I am using below function to merge 2 collections, one from DB and the other from User Inputs. I want to verify during validation which records are from DB and which are local.

```
def tags=(arg)        
    if arg.is_a?(Array)
        @ids = arg.map{|x| x[:id]}
        tags <<  Tags.where(id: @ids )
    else
        super
    end
end
```

I tried the following inside a custom validation function but it is returning false for all records even records entered by user:

```
def tags_validator        
    tags.each  do |item| 
        errors.add(:new_record , item.new_record?)
    end
end
```

my JSON is as follow (I an just passing IDs for tags):

```
{
    "data": {

        "name": "Johnny English",
            "tags" :  
            [   {"id" :3 } , {"id" :4 }    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also not convinced this is necessary. If you have a `has_many :tags, through: ...` relationship here then assigning tags directly to that relationship creates the intermediate records automatically. It's actually quite handy.

Comment: @tadman I have already relationship, I just need to differentiate between new and old for different purposes and not for insertion/update of records.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you could wrangle your incoming JSON parameters into the models used in the back-end, and this conversion is the explicit responsibility of your controller. Pushing it down to the model layer makes things extremely messy, the model shouldn't need to know about the parameter format at all.

Comment: I am already doing so and controller is already taking care. But at some point when updating data , I need to create a custom validation. in which I want to differentiate between old and new records for the 'Tags' collection.

Comment: That's fine, but the model should only be seeing other models, not arbitrary JSON structures. You can easily compute which tags are new using `@model.tags - @tags` where you've resolved the tags with `@tags = Tags.where(id: @ids)` like you have here. You've got mostly the right code, it's just in the wrong place which complicates things. You can also set up a `before_validation` trigger to capture the state of the tags, and an `after_save` do do stuff if/when they're changed.

Comment: Is it a good practice in Ruby to define a global variable where I can hold the original data received from user before merge it with values from DB ?

Comment: Global? Never. A controller instance variable? That's fine, in fact, pretty typical. The controller's local environment is trashed at the end of each request so you can do whatever you need to do, it all gets cleaned up.